# Add header to <img> GET

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is there any way to add a header to a standard HTML  tag?

What we have is:
/path/to/image.png

Except this is actually a RESTful endpoint, and it requires a userID header.

```
GET /path/to/image.png
Header
userId: BobLoblaw
```

This returns a bytestream and poof, image.

However, we hope to use this right in an image tag.  Is that possible without Apache forcing an outgoing userId?

I'm hoping for something like

```
imageProvider.get().then(function(response) {
   // do something with the resultant bytestream
})
```

Note - this is NOT base64 transcoding.  It's an actual image stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You don't get to control the request headers that the  browser sends along with a GET request for an `<img>` tag.

Use a query parameter in the URL.

Comment: OK.  Good idea.  Was thinking that or a cookie instead of header maybe.  -edit (I didn't mean 'decent' to seem derogatory)